# Throwing exception in MultiTenantConnectionProvider, exhausts the connections in Connection Pool

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I am using multi tenancy by schema in MySQL as,

```
class SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider : MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var dataSource: DataSource

  @Throws(SQLException::class)
  override fun getAnyConnection() = this.dataSource.connection

  @Throws(SQLException::class)
  override fun releaseAnyConnection(connection: Connection) {
    connection.close()
  }

  @Throws(SQLException::class)
  override fun getConnection(tenantIdentifier: String): Connection {
    val connection = this.anyConnection
    try {
      connection.createStatement().execute("USE $tenantIdentifier ")
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
      throw SQLException("Could not alter JDBC connection to schema [$tenantIdentifier]")
    }

    return connection
  }
...
}
```

My connection pool size is 10, now if any invalid `tenantIdentifier` is passed 10 times, 10 connections are exhausted, after that application is unable to acquire any connection.

Tried throwing `Exception, HibernateException` and it didn't help. Using connection with `default schema` will fetch wrong results. Is there a way to handle this scenario in `getConnection()`, to not to exhaust connection limits?

Comment: I hope you also override ```public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) ``` and closing the conncection here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below configuration should work, overriding `public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection)`  will ensure connection get released back to the connection pool.

```
   public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl
            implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, Stoppable {
        private final ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProviderUtils.buildConnectionProvider( "master" );

        @Override
        public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
            return connectionProvider.getConnection();
        }

        @Override
        public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connectionProvider.closeConnection( connection );
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
            final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
            try {
                connection.createStatement().execute( "USE " + tenanantIdentifier );
            }
            catch ( SQLException e ) {
                throw new HibernateException(
                        "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
                                tenantIdentifier + "]",
                        e
                );
            }
            return connection;
        }

        @Override
        public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            try {
                connection.createStatement().execute( "USE master" );
            }
            catch ( SQLException e ) {
                // on error, throw an exception to make sure the connection is not returned to the pool.
                // your requirements may differ
                throw new HibernateException(
                        "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
                                tenantIdentifier + "]",
                        e
                );
            }
            connectionProvider.closeConnection( connection );
        }

        ...
    }
```

Next, fine tuning the datasource configuration in spring boot:

```
# Number of ms to wait before throwing an exception if no connection is available.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000

# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
```

Reference : [Working with datasources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

If the issue still persist, go ahead with datasource connection pooling mechanism support such as Hikari etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am using HikariCP and releasing connection in releaseConnection, as mentioned by you. This didn't work. Now I tried to close the connection in getConnection() while error, it solved the problem

Comment: ok great but you dont need to close the connection in getConnection(). definitely the caller will call the releaseConnection method even if an exception is thrown while getting the connection.Please double check the releaseConnection method which gives you connection instance to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

closing connection, in case of error solved the problem.

```
@Throws(SQLException::class)
  override fun getConnection(tenantIdentifier: String): Connection {
    val connection = this.anyConnection
    try {
      connection.createStatement().execute("USE $tenantIdentifier ")
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
      connection.close()
      throw SQLException("Could not alter JDBC connection to schema [$tenantIdentifier]")
    }

    return connection
  }
```